# Reduced Row Echelon Form. Is there only one correct way?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm fairly new to linear algebra. Im studying for an exam and was given the following matrix: \begin{array}{l}1&-2&-1&-3\\2&-4&2&2\end{array} 
I was able to turn it into \begin{array}{l}1&-2&-1&-3\\0&0&4&8\end{array}
However, past this I'm confused. This may be a really trivial question so I apologize in advanced but can't seem to find the "right" way to turn it into RREF. For the second pivot the textbook had: 1/4R2 -> R2. However, I was trying to see if I could also do R2 + (3)R1 -> R2, but could not come up with the same answer? Is there only one correct way to do this?

Comment: If you add triple the first row to the second row, you ruin the zero below the pivot in the first column.

Comment: In general, there are multiple sequences of elementary row operations that you can take to get to RREF and assuming you applied each step correctly you will arrive at the same final form.  There are very explicitly written algorithms which you can follow [like this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Pseudocode) which will guarantee you an answer with no decision making required on your part at all.  Such strictly defined algorithms might not necessarily be the quickest or easiest to do arithmetic with however, so deviating from it a bit can be good with practice.